# numerically evaluate a continued fraction

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am looking at a continued fraction of the form
$$
F_n = \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{p_1}{1+\cfrac{p_2}{1+\cfrac{p_3}{1+\ldots}}}}
$$
where $p_n$ is a function I know. For simplicity I just take it to $p_n=n$ for now. I wish to evaluate this fraction numerically for a given $n$, but I am having conceptual difficulties on how to do it.

I need a starting point, so I first evaluate (I take $n=4$ for the sake of the question):
$$
x_0 = \frac{p_3}{1+p_4}
$$
This is where I am stuck. How to go "up the ladder" recursively? I'd be happy to get a hint or two.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the write-up in [*NR*](http://books.google.com/books?id=1aAOdzK3FegC&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=numerically+evaluate+a+continued+fraction&source=bl&ots=3iThDaFpng&sig=4cBdBE0iAcrt4hxFxWB5kpEHmSQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=et25UZHoDIfHiwKQ7oDgDw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=numerically%20evaluate%20a%20continued%20fraction&f=false), including the references and that will get you going.

Comment: You’ll find a lot of information in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction), including the basic recurrence formulas. The article covers the more general case in which your $1$’s are replaced by arbitrary values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The continued fraction can be evaluated "top down," which is useful since that makes computations extensible.

Let $F_n=\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$.  The numbers $a_k,b_k$ satisfy the following system of recurrences. 
$$a_{-1}=0,\qquad a_0=1, \qquad a_k=a_{k-1}+p_ka_{k-2},$$ 
$$b_{-1}=1,\qquad b_0=1, \qquad b_k=b_{k-1}+p_kb_{k-2},$$
for $k\ge 1$.

Comment: i was thinking more in terms of pseudo-code that would help in evaluating a general continued fraction

Comment: @BillyJean: Particularly for the top down version given above, the pseudo-code (and indeed code) should follow quickly from the recurrences.

Comment: @BillyJean: The pseudocode is in the answer: set `p[0]=a[0]; q[0]=1; p[1]=a[1]*p[0]; q[1] = a[1];` and in a loop for $k \ge 2$ evaluate `p[k] = a[k]*p[k-1] + p[k-2]; q[k] = a[k]*q[k-1] + q[k-2];`. The fraction `p[n] / q[n]` is the numerical value of the continued fraction up to $n$ terms.

Comment: thanks; when you guys say *simple continued fraction*, do you mean that $p_i$ are positive integers, or that $i$ are positive integers? If it is the latter, then it is a very general result you have posted!

Comment: @BillyJean: You don't need the $a_i$s (note the difference in notation between your question and this answer: what you call $p_n$ is $a_n$ here) to be positive integers, or even integers: they can be arbitrary real numbers, or even complex numbers or members of some field. :-) The proof just uses properties of addition, multiplication and division; it uses nothing about the signs of the numbers.

Comment: With that recurrence you get $p_k=0$ for all $k$ when $a_0=0$, which can’t be right. I believe that it should be $p_k=p_{k-1}+a_kp_{k-2}$ and similarly for $q_k$, and that the initial values should be $p_0=a_0$, $p_1=a_0+a_1$, $q_0=1$, and $q_1=1$, as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Fundamental_recurrence_formulas).

Comment: Thank you. Fixed. Saw comment finally, there were inbox problems.